# Why does "pipenv install" install a different version than what's in the Pipfile?

Tags: python, pipenv

Pipfile:

```
[packages]
xgboost = "1.4.2"
```

I've also tried  `xgboost = "1.4"` using the command `pipenv install` for a new pipenv environment.

When I check the installed version using `pipenv run pip freeze` :

```
numpy==1.22.0
scipy==1.7.3
xgboost==1.5.1
```

Why can't I install xgboost 1.4.2 ?

I can work around it by downloading the wheel file or using the url to install 1.4.2:

```
xgboost = {path = "./xgboost-1.4.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl"}
xgboost = {file = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/60/845dd265c7265d3bd44906d1c15be2908ff0655b32d9000935aeaeef6677/xgboost-1.4.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  I should code:

```
[packages]
xgboost = "==1.4.2"
```